# Custom Definitions in Bigquery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm pretty new to Bigquery/Firebase/GA even SQL. (btw, if you have some good experience or recommendations where I can start learning, that would be great!)

But I have main issue with Bigquery that needs solving right now. I'm kinda trying all sources I can get some info/tips from. I hope this community will be one of them.

So my issue is with Custom Definitions. we have them defined in Google Analytics . We want to divide users with this definition and analyze them separately:

My question is: where/how can I find these custom definitions in bigquery to filter my Data? I have normal fields, like user ID, Timestamps etc. but can't find these custom definitions.

I have been doing some research but still don't have a clear answer, if someone can give me some tips or mby a solution I would be forever in debt ! xD

I got one solution from the other community which looks like this, but I couldn't make it work, my bigquery doesn't recognize customDimensions as it says in the error.

> select cd.* from table, unnest(customDimensions) cd

Comment: kaggle has two courses on SQL in BigQuery: https://www.kaggle.com/learn/overview

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [custom function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators), [Stored Procedure](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#bigquery_scripting)  on Bigquery as per your requirements.
To apply formal Filter over filed like user ID, & Timestamps, you can simply apply standard SQL filter as given below:-

```
SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE USER_ID = 'User1' OR Timestamps = 'YYY-MM-DDTHH:MM'
```

Moreover, [unnest](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest_operator) is used to split data on fields, do you have data which need to be spited ?
I could help you more if you share what are you expecting from your SQL.

Comment: thx for the answer,
Yea, I kinda figured out how to select basic fields like useriD etc. 
but my problems begin when we talk about customDimensions that i have defined in google analytics tho, and yes, i guess this data needs splitting. i have tried this (looks like i can't post images here so i uploaded it on external site): https://ibb.co/NnXy04Q , but Bigquery doesn't recognize customDimensions, is it because i'm searching in wrong table? i dunno. Is there any way to see all the tables and their fields that i have in my project so then i can write my sql code according to that maybe?

Comment: here is screenshot of customdimensions in google analytics i'm talking about https://preview.redd.it/1fu3ujo7jeq61.png?width=1618&format=png&auto=webp&s=5611f4eb458918ca01310eb34020715fa4f402f4

Comment: If i understand correctly 'customDimensions' is a table not Column ? If that is the case then you can not have a table in 'unnest' on a table, it should be only on columns that too on column of fist table.  To solve this problem you should join 2 table first on joining keys then apply filter conditions on joining data.

Comment: To view table structure and all table on project ... just hover cursor over table name on Bigquery editor ... then press control and click on table name it will open table structure on Bigquery Webpage.

Comment: yes, but it seems I need ga_sessions_ Dataset, which i can't find for my project.
I found public dataset one (bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_) but can i find the one for my project?

Answer (score 0):

Your custom dimensions sit in arrays called `customDimensions`. These arrays are basically a list of structs - where each struct has 2 fields: `key` and `value`. So they basically look like this example: `[ {key:1, value:'banana'}, {key:4, value:'yellow'}, {key:8, value:'premium'} ]` where `key` is the index of the custom dimension you've set up in Google Analytics.

There are 3 `customDimensions` arrays! Two of them are nested within other arrays. If you want to work with those you really need to get proficient in working with arrays. E.g. the function `unnest()` turns arrays into table format on which you can run SQL.

- customDimensions[]
- hits[]

  - customDimensions[]
  - product[]

    - customDimensions[]

Example 1 with subquery on session-scoped custom dimension 3:

```sql
select
  fullvisitorid,
  visitStartTime,
  (select value from unnest(customDimensions) where key=3) cd3
from
  ga_sessions_20210202
```

Example 2 with a lateral cross join - you're enlargening the table here - not ideal:

```sql
select
  fullvisitorid,
  visitStartTime,  
  cd.*
from ga_session_20210202 cross join unnest(customDimensions) as cd
```

All names are case-sensitive - in one of your screenshots you used a wrong name with a "c" being uppercase.

This page can help you up your array game: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays - just work through all the examples and play around in the query editor

Comment: Thank you so much ! 
I think I understood the logic there, but I have one question, about "from" part of the code, you have ga_session_yymmdd right? how should I use this example exactly in my case? coz I think I have some Idea what fields I need but misunderstanding where to take these fields from.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean - there is an overview of all fields here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089

Comment: yea, I have seen that but my question was different. Sorry, mby coz of my lack of knowledge i couldn't state it well.
i'll try one more time. this is my screen after i put the code in Biguery https://ibb.co/mzXkHWM It doesn't recognize "ga_sessions20210202" part. if you will try to explain this i think u will also answer my question

Comment: so after some more research, i found public dataset for ga_sessions_ (`bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_) in which i can write your code and it works. but can i find same dataset for my project too? to get data from my private google analyitcs, not the public one

Comment: Yes, you have to export the data first - here's a how-to https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092